# Use beginBitmapFill with existing movieclip/shape? (Animate CC)

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, adobe-animate

All the tutorials for using beginBitmapFill seem to center around dynamically drawing an object.  Is it possible to simply apply a bitmap fill to an existing shape that's inside a movieclip?  I know I can do this manually by selecting the shape and selecting a bitmap in the Color panel.. but is it possible to do it with code?  This is what I'm trying and it's not giving errors, but it's also not working:

```
grl.tops.shapes.graphics.beginBitmapFill(new cubepattern(), null, true, false);
```

Comment: Probably, possible, but it is not a simple way. You can read and (probably) figure the shape of strokes already present on **Graphics** object, then replicate it with transparent lines applying the fill. Quite an endeavor of a task. https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData()

Comment: Better use a mask to draw that fill over an existing shape. Otherwise yes, fills are represented in a list returned by `readGraphicsData()` that you might decide to compile from two sources, one the shape you want to get filled, the other a shape that you fill with required bitmap, you get path elements from first source and fill elements from second source, then construct a new shape and feed its `graphics.drawGraphicsData` with the constructed list.

Comment: What you have tried just adds the bitmap fill object to the *end* of that shape's graphics data, so should you decide to draw something on that graphics, then call `endFill()` it would get filled with your bitmap. Otherwise yes, it's just unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have commented, you can use readGraphicsData and drawGraphicsData respectively. It's even not over-complicated. Simply loop through the IGraphicsData of your desired shape, stop as soon as you've found an instance of the GraphicsBitmapFill class, create a new instance with another BitmapFill and finally apply the changes to the original shape.

Well, a picture is worth a thousand words.
Here's an example. This might seem a bit long but there's just a whole lot of code to prepare a shape and load images to be used as bitmap fills.

Set your eyes on the **process()** function.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Loader
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.IGraphicsData;
    import flash.display.GraphicsBitmapFill;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var bitmapData1:BitmapData;
        private var bitmapData2:BitmapData;
        private var masterSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var texturesLoaded:int = 0;
        private var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        public function Main():void
        {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("textureA.jpg"));
            addChild(masterSprite);
            masterSprite.x = masterSprite.y = 200;
        }

        private function onComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            switch (texturesLoaded)
            {
                case 0: 
                    bitmapData1 = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;
                    loader.load(new URLRequest("textureB.jpg"));
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    bitmapData2 = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;
                    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
                    drawStar();
                    process();
            }
            texturesLoaded++;
        }

        private function process():void
        {
            var tempShape:Shape = Shape(masterSprite.getChildAt(0));

            var graphicsData:Vector.<IGraphicsData> = tempShape.graphics.readGraphicsData();
            for (var a:int = 0; a < graphicsData.length; a++)
            {
                if (getQualifiedClassName(graphicsData[a]) == "flash.display::GraphicsBitmapFill")
                {
                    var bitmapFill:GraphicsBitmapFill = new GraphicsBitmapFill(bitmapData2);
                    graphicsData[a] = bitmapFill; break;
                }
            }
            tempShape.graphics.drawGraphicsData(graphicsData);
        }

        private function drawStar():void
        {
            var angles:Array = new Array(0, 36, 72, 108, 144, 180, 216, 252, 288, 324, 360);
            var innerRadius:int = 40;
            var outerRadius:int = 80;
            var shape:Shape = new Shape();
            shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData1);
            shape.graphics.moveTo(0 + Math.cos(angles[a] * (Math.PI / 180)) * outerRadius, 0 + Math.sin(angles[a] * (Math.PI / 180)) * outerRadius);
            for (var a:int = 0; a < angles.length; a++)
            {
                angles[a] -= 90;
                if (a % 2 == 0)
                {
                    shape.graphics.lineTo(0 + Math.cos(angles[a] * (Math.PI / 180)) * outerRadius, 0 + Math.sin(angles[a] * (Math.PI / 180)) * outerRadius);
                }
                else
                {
                    shape.graphics.lineTo(0 + Math.cos(angles[a] * (Math.PI / 180)) * innerRadius, 0 + Math.sin(angles[a] * (Math.PI / 180)) * innerRadius);
                }
            }
            shape.graphics.endFill();
            masterSprite.addChild(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I'm trying to test this out but I don't know much about external as code.  I've saved this into a .as file, then created an .fla in the same folder, and added the name of the as in the "Class" field and called Main();  Is that right?  Now I'm getting an error that the location of the file isn't what it says in "Main" I dunno..

Comment: What if I don't need to do so much by code, just want to copy shape of movieclip "tops" and fill it with bitmap "cubepattern"?  I mostly use the stuff in the process() function, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Though you may need to import the required classes as above and reference **grl.tops.shapes** as the tempShape in the process() function.

Comment: I'm having trouble doing that.  Most variations I try yield a "type coercion failed" error.  I imagine the whole crux of the thing depends on making this line work.
var tempShape:Shape = Shape(grl.tops.shapes);
var tempShape:Shape = Shape(grl.tops.shapes.getChildAt(0));

Comment: Looks like your DisplayObject ain't a Shape. Unfortunately I can just guess what it really is. You could try **var tempShape:Sprite = Sprite(grl.tops.shapes);** or do a trace(grl.tops.shapes); and look at the debug panel what type it outputs.

Comment: Oh!  You're right; it was further nested. Found the shape now, thank you.

Comment: Last step, I'm just trying to sub in for my bitmap in the library.  `var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new cubepattern();` cubepattern being the linkageId of my bitmap in the library.  I'm trying variations of this and most don't give errors but I don't see anything happen.  This code replaces the original shape or draws one above it?  Do I need to further specify where to draw the new shape?

Comment: Actually the code is looping through the IGraphicsData of your shape, stops if it finds a BitmapFill and
replaces it. Maybe it still doesn't loop through the proper shape? Put a trace statement in the if() condition
to see if it finds a BitmapFill at all or even a trace(graphicsData[a]) in the for loop.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!  Great explanation.  It wasn't finding a BitmapFill because it traces back GraphicsSolidFill.  Okay, I switched it to find a `"flash.display::GraphicsSolidFill"` and that worked, and it filled it with the bitmap!  With minor tweaking I see that this will absolutely do what I need.  Thank you!!!

Comment: if I can bug you about one last thing, I amended the if statement to search for a Solid or Bitmap fill.  In some cases of calling the process() function, it doesn't just override the current fill but seems to draw on top of it.. eg, the transparent bitmap seems to be overdrawn each time, making the lines thicker etc.  Is it adding multiple fills and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Yep, this needs to strip existing graphics data off `tempShape`, as `drawGraphicsData()` does not replace the entire set of graphics data existing on the shape, but rather adds to its tail, effectively overlapping whatever was there before. So, just call `graphics.clear()` before drawing new set of graphics data, should do.

Comment: Can I do anything to manipulate the bitmap?  It looks quite pixellated.  I checked off Allow Smoothing in the bitmap's properties (does this utilize those settings?).  I tried doubling the size of the shape then halving the size of the parent, to double the resolution, which worked, but it still pixellates badly at some zooms.

Comment: I think I figured it out!  Had to add `bitmapFill.smooth = true;`

Comment: In case it helps anyone later, I was also able to increase the resolution of the bitmap by creating a matrix scaled to half, then applying it to the GraphicsBitmapFill

Comment: Hopefully the last issue.. I'm trying to re-run the function whenever the movieclip goes to a new frame (and a new shape is presented) and the behaviour is curious.. It works when moving backwards through frames.  But when I move forwards through frames (eg. from frame 3 to 7), it doesn't draw the shape again.  It keeps the old shape.  Why is this and how can I get around this?  I'm so close to fully harnessing the power of this!!!

Comment: I couldn't find a workaround for this so I had to switch to an everything-existing-at-once and toggling visibility hack (instead of switching frames)